# successfully installed packages in R but unable to use

Tags: r

i have successfully installed packages(arules) in R,but when i am trying to use 
those packages by using

```
library("arules")
data("Adult")
```

it does not do any thing neither it generate any error,only cursor blink once, now i stuck over there so kindly help me out thanks
[image: in this screenshot can easily understand what problem it has]

Comment: What where you expecting to happen when you ran that line? That should just load the data set into your current environment. Try typing `Adult` to see the data.

Comment: Type `str(Adult)`

Comment: also, you do not need the `" "` inside the parentheses when calling a package with `library()` or `require()`